# UITableViewCell showing "Label" repeatedly

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In the `UITableViewCell` the name of the song that must be appeared is shown with "Label" from storyboard. The code of controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AudioCell") as AudioCell
    var mp3file: AnyObject = mp3sPaths[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = mp3file.lastPathComponent
    cell.playIcon.text = "▶️"
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var mp3file = mp3sPaths[indexPath.row] as NSString
    var mp3URL: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(mp3file)!
    var error: NSError?
    audioPlayer?.stop()
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3URL, error: &error)
    audioPlayer?.play()
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? AudioCell {
        cell.playIcon.text = "◾️"
    }
}
```

And the code of AudioCell class:
    class AudioCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var playIcon: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

The screenshot of the app is [there:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RyeX.png)

Comment: Do you have a label in storyboard?

Comment: In your view controller you reference textLabel? but in your cell it's titleLabel. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because in tableView function you are setting name of cell textLabel

```
cell.textLabel?.text = mp3file.lastPathComponent
```

and in your cell you have title label

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
```

All you need to do is in your tableView function

```
cell.titleLabel?.text = mp3file.lastPathComponent
```

and be sure that textLabel does not exist in story board tableview cell